# Check if list of integers is in Python Pandas Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to check if some integers in a list exist in Index.

My database is something like this:

(My UC column below is actually my INDEX)

| UC | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -9.6732 | -35.745 |
| 2 | -9.6765 | -35.74 |
| 3 | -9.67121 | -35.745 |
| 4 | -9.6712 | -35.745 |
| 5 | -9.67115 | -35.76 |

And the code I've built:

```
base = pd.read_csv('database.txt', sep=",")
base.set_index('UC', inplace = True)

dataInput = [int(x) for x in input('Digite as UCs: ').split(",")]
size = len(dataInput)

# That list built above is what I need to check if those "UC" exist in INDEX of my dataframe
# I've tried this, but doesn't worked:

print(base['UC'].isin(dataInput))

# I need to check if all the items in my list exist in order to create exceptions to errors and print just what is in my dataframe
```

Comment: `isin` accepts a list, you may want `base['UC'].isin([132])`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit the [132] to "dataInput", I was testing when I copied the code here hahah. When I put 132 it works... But when I use dataInput and some of those inputs doens't exists in the index, it gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not sure from the phrasing of your question if you want to identify the entries in the list which are not in the index or if you want to identify index values not in the list.  Also, if the second case is true, I am not sure if you just need the list of indices or if you want the rows which for which the index is not in the list.  For these reasons I have provided two possible approaches which both utilize sets as a way to determine if an index is in the list or not.
Given:
dataframe of the form:

```
    LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
UC      
1   9.67320 35.745
2   9.67650 35.740
3   9.67121 35.745
4   9.67120 35.745
5   9.67115 35.760
```

InputList of the form:
[2, 7, 3]

Approach #1:
Determine if the inputList contains values not in df.index

```
diflist = list(set(inputList).difference(set(df.index.to_list())))
```

Yields:

```
[7]
```

Approach #2
Determine if df.index contains values not in inputList

```
difList = list(set(df.index.to_list()).difference(set(inputList)))
```

Yields:

```
[1, 4, 5]
```

Once you have the list of indices not in your dataframe you can then print the dataframe rows if that is your final objective.